# append number to string but not as ascii value

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read bytes from file and send via UDP.
Below is code. In This code blk_cntr is set as 1.

```
     msg_temp='\x00'+'\x03'+'\x00'+blk_cntr+str(filedata[0:(blocksize*i)])
```

It gives me error "TypeError: must be str, not int"

When i change it to

```
       str(blk_cntr)
```

then no error but UDP pack-ate consist of ascii value of 1 i want it to be plain 1 not its ASCII value.

I also not sure

```
   str(filedata.....)
```

I want msg_temp to be as 00 03 00 01 etc
is right way to do that.

Comment: You might like to look at the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library... If not, then try `chr(blk_cntr)`.

Comment: @Attie chr will also convert it to ascii value

Comment: No, it'll turn it into a string ... `chr(1) == '\x01'` which I presume is what you want?

Comment: Sorry. You are right.

Comment: can you tell me how  can i get file data bytes to msg_temp. If i use chr their it gives error as integer is required(got bytes)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library. Manual assembly of binary payloads isn't very fun.

Presuming your packet format is big endian with the following fields:

- 16-bit integer
- 16-bit integer
- variable length string

You would do something like this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('>hh', 3, 1) + 'some_test_data'.encode('ascii')
>>> data
b'\x00\x03\x00\x01some_test_data'
```

If you want to read this payload data from a file, then you either need to encode the string, or open the file for binary I/O.

#### Encode the String

Opening a file for "*text-mode*" I/O will produce a `string` on `read()` - this is the default if `t` or `b` are not given in the `mode` string when calling `open()`.
To use the returned string with the binary data (`bytes`), you must encode it.
Common encodings are `ascii` or `utf-8`.

```
$ echo -n "some_test_data" > data_file
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('>hh', 3, 1)
>>> payload = open('data_file', 'r').read()
>>> data += payload.encode('ascii')
>>> data
b'\x00\x03\x00\x01some_test_data'
```

#### Binary I/O

Alternatively, open the file for binary I/O - give `b` in the `mode` string when calling `open()`.
This will be necessary if your file has any binary data in it.

```
$ echo -n "some_test_data" > data_file
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('>hh', 3, 1)
>>> data += open('data_file', 'rb').read()
>>> data
b'\x00\x03\x00\x01some_test_data'
```